# gray screen with Itune bought movies

Tags: itunes, quicktime

I have been watching movies on Itune for a while now, so this is a new problem. This gray screen has appeared in the last two movies I rented. It doesn't appear when I rent TV shows. I contacted apple via email and the person who responded said: 
"you probably need to install the latest QuickTime upgrade. You can download QuickTime free of charge from the Apple website". THIS IS WHERE THINGS START TO GET CONFUSING. I have a Macbook 10.4.11 BUT the Quicktime upgrade  requires a Leopard System MAC OS X v10.5. and up. SO WHAT DO I DO NOW? It cant mean I cant watch movies on Itune, can it? What am I missing here? This is confusing. Thanks a head of time for any help. Nora

Comment: ok, seems like I have quicktime version 7.6.4 if that helps.

Comment: Have you run a software update from the Apple menu at the top-left of your menu bar?  It might pull the correct Quicktime upgrade for Tiger (instead of doing it through the Apple site).

Comment: did that and it doesn't seem to have made a difference. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS THE BEST ANSWER I HAVE GOTTEN FROM A FRIEND OF MINE SO FAR. SEEMS CRAZY

Here's the best answer I could find. http://community.avid.com/forums/p/71510/399964.aspx

Translated into English, what it's saying is that unless you upgrade to Leopard or Snow Leopard (which is actually worth doing--it's much faster and compatible with more software), you'll need to run an older version of Quicktime, version 7.4.5 for Tiger and replace your newer version with this older one.